# How to convert a "Single line text" column into "Person or Group column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How to convert a "Single line text" column into "Person or Group" column in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot change the type of column after the column is created.
- However, if you have names present in "Single line text" column then 
  you can create a "Person or Group" column.
- Keep them aside by modifying the display position.
- Under "Quick Edit", copy and paste the name values of "Single line text" column to "Person or Group" column.

Comment: yes, this way we performing now, but It's not request

I have a list, which i have uploaded in share point

In that list some columns needs to be converted to "Person or Group" - kindly help us to advice

Comment: @Guna It's not possible to convert.
Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you! :)

Comment: @Guna Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Comment: Hi Sohali, am new user for Stack Workflow, kindly guide me to how to accept this answer and do Upvote. it seems there is no Option or button here.

Comment: @Guna Just click on the tick symbol to accept the answer and click on the up arrow button to upvote besides my answer.

Comment: @Guna Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Comment: This is not entirely true. A text column can be changed to things like multiple text, choice, number and date - but not more complex fields such as people, hyperlink and managed metadata. Please update your answer to reflect this...